# Whom is the word "he" referring to in Sahih Muslim 1598?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

[Sahih Muslim 1598](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1598):

> Jabir said that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) cursed the accepter of interest
> and its payer, and one who records it, and the two witnesses, and
> **he** said:
>
> They are all equal.

**Whom is the word "he" referring to in this hadith? Narrator Jabir? or the Prophet SAW?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He refers certainly to the prophet () as he knows better whether they are regarded equal or not.

For an explanation:

> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
> That is, (they are all the same) in terms of being cursed, because they co-operated in that.
> End quote from Fataawa Noor ‘ala ad-Darb, 16/2 (Source: islamqa #[202904](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/202904/riba-is-haraam-for-the-one-who-takes-it-and-the-one-who-pays-it-and-it-is-haraam-to-help-with-it-in-any-way-whatsoever))

And for a backup that it is the prophet who say this a quote from Mirqat al-Mafatih the commentary on Mishkat al-Masabih -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=5596&bk_no=79&flag=1)-:

> ( وقال ) ، أي : النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم
> (and he said): meaning: the prophet Allah's prayer and blessing be upon him.